# VSCode autocompleting with optional arguments

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, intellisense

i'm new to coding and when i use autocomplete in vscode is there way for it to autocomplete with optional arguments?
example:
auto complete `prin` to`print(sep=..., end=..., file=..., flush=...)`instead of `print()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way doing exactly what you want per se...but, you can create a code snippet fairly easily that does exactly that.
You can read about it more at: [How to create VSCode snippets](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/userdefinedsnippets).

Good luck!